# Specify a single word property in react using React.createElement

Tags: reactjs

I tried to dynamically create a line chart like:

```
<LineChart
    axes
    dataPoints
    xDomainRange={[0, 100]}
    yDomainRange={[0, 100]}
    width={500}
    height={250}
     ...
/>
```

but using `React.createElement` like:

```
React.createElement(LinkChart, {xDomainRange:[0, 100], ...})
```

How can I deal with those "single word" properties like "axes" and "dataPoints"?

Any suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [**DOC**](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true): **Props Default to “True”**:

If you pass no value for a prop, it defaults to true. These two JSX expressions are equivalent:

```
<ComponentName autocomplete />

<ComponentName autocomplete={true} />
```

---

> How can I deal with those "single word" properties like "axes" and
>   "dataPoints"?

What these single word property means in `reactjs`, it means:

```
<LineChart>
    axes={true}
    dataPoints={true}
    .....
</LineChart>
```

Shorter way of writing this is:

```
<LineChart>
    axes
    dataPoints
    .....
</LineChart>
```

So in `React.createElement`, you can write:

```
React.createElement(
    LinkChart, 
    {xDomainRange:[0, 100], axes: true, dataPoints: true, ....}
)
```

Comment: Yes, that made it. Thanks